# How can I get InstanceInfo from Spring Cloud Netflix's when client disconnects?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I want to get the `InstanceInfo` of the disconnected client  with `EurekaInstanceCanceledEvent` event on Spring Boot for accessing the client `metadataMap`. Is there any way to do so without rolling my own solution? Can't seem to find any way around!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you talking about the client of the current spring boot application?

Comment: @spencergibb I was referring the Eureka server. It dispatches the event `EurekaInstanceCanceledEvent` when a client disconnects, but doesn't supply the IntanceInfo for the disconnected client.